# Reverse a String , Code was not working properly

Tags: java

I think theres something wrong with my syntax. So please help me with those syntax:

```
public class Main { 

  public static void main(String arg[]) { 
    String number = "1234";
    System.out.println("original String: " + number);
    String reversed = inPlaceReverse(number);
    System.out.println("reversed String: " + reversed); 
  } 

  public  String inPlaceReverse(final String input) {
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input); 
    int length = builder.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) { 
      final char current = builder.charAt(i);
      final int otherEnd = length - i - 1;
      builder.setCharAt(i, .charAt(otherEnd)); // swap 
      builder.setCharAt(otherEnd, current); 
    }
    return builder.toString(); 
  }

}
```

Reverse function is not working properly.

Comment: `number = new StringBuilder(number).reverse().toString();`

Comment: your code looks fine to me. You just need to make the method `inPlaceReverse`  to `static` and change line `builder.setCharAt(i, .charAt(otherEnd));` to `builder.setCharAt(i, input.charAt(otherEnd));` which probably shows you compile time error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some errors in your code.

1) `error: illegal start of expression builder.setCharAt(i, .charAt(otherEnd));`

correction: `builder.setCharAt(i, **builder**.charAt(otherEnd));`

2) `error: non-static method inPlaceReverse(String) cannot be referenced from a static context`

This is because you have declared main() as static whereas your isPlaceReverse() is non-static. You cannot reference a non-static member within a static member.

Change your function definition to `public  **static** String inPlaceReverse(final String input)`

After you make the above corrections, you'll get the desired output:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String number = "1234";
        System.out.println("original String: " + number);
        String reversed = inPlaceReverse(number);
        System.out.println("reversed String: " + reversed);
    }


    public static String inPlaceReverse(final String input) {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input);
        int length = builder.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
            final char current = builder.charAt(i);
            final int otherEnd = length - i - 1;
            builder.setCharAt(i, builder.charAt(otherEnd)); // swap
            builder.setCharAt(otherEnd, current);
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Output
original String: 1234
reversed String: 4321

Comment: It might help the OP more if you explain where you found errors, and how you fixed them?

Comment: Thanks alot!, Your code is working properly, Helped me a lot, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

`StringBuilder` has a function that does this:

`StringBuilder.reverse()`  You can also append .toString() to this call to get it back into a String.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()

Comment: In practice, this is probably the way to go.  But, this doesn't directly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Update your reverse logic to :

```
public static  String inPlaceReverse(final String input) {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input); 
            int length = builder.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) { 
                final char current = builder.charAt(i);
                final char otherEnd = builder.charAt(length - i - 1);
                builder.setCharAt(i, otherEnd); // swap 
                builder.setCharAt(length-i-1, current); 
           }
            return builder.toString(); 
}
```

A more appropriate way will be:

```
 public static String inPlaceReverse(final String input) { // make it static
                final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input);
                return builder.reverse().toString();
 }
```